# Unable to convert deep cloning to immer

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm working on some legacy code that used to do full deep cloning of the redux state in a react application. Here's the original boilerplate, which is used as a basis for the reducers used in the application:

```
export default (initialState, handlers = {}, promiseActionTypes = []) =>
  (state = initialState, action) => {
    let nextState = _.cloneDeep(state)
    promiseActionTypes.forEach((actionType) => {
      if (action.type === `@@REMOTE/${actionType}_REQUEST`) {
        nextState.isFetching = true
      }
      if (action.type === `@@REMOTE/${actionType}_SUCCESS`) {
        nextState = {
          ...nextState,
          data: _.get(action, 'data.storeData', action.data),
          isFetching: false,
          isInited: true,
        }
      }
      if (action.type === `@@REMOTE/${actionType}_FAILURE`) {
        nextState.isFetching = false
      }
    })
    if (handlers.hasOwnProperty(action.type)) {
      nextState = handlers[action.type](nextState, action, _.cloneDeep(state))
    }
    return nextState
  }
```

Those clone deeps are all big no-nos, so I'm trying to leverage immer's produce function to mutate drafted copies of the state before returning the new state.

Problem is, I've been unable to get everything in sync. Some pieces of state won't update correctly here or there. Here's my attempt at refactor so far:

```
import produce from 'immer'

export default (initialState, handlers = {}, promiseActionTypes = []) =>
  (state = initialState, action) => {
    return produce(state, (draft) => {
      promiseActionTypes.forEach((actionType) => {
        if (action.type === `@@REMOTE/${actionType}_REQUEST`) {
          draft.isFetching = true
        }
        if (action.type === `@@REMOTE/${actionType}_SUCCESS`) {
          draft.data = _.get(action, 'data.storeData', action.data)
          draft.isFetching = false
          draft.isInited = true
        }
        if (action.type === `@@REMOTE/${actionType}_FAILURE`) {
          draft.isFetching = false
        }

        return draft
      })

      if (handlers.hasOwnProperty(action.type)) {
        return handlers[action.type](draft, action, state)
      }

      return draft
    })
  }
```

I tried to unfreeze the touched objects, but still no dice. Is my implementation just off? Or am I misunderstanding how produce works?

Hell, do I ever need something like immer if I'm just trying to get those two lodash `cloneDeep` calls out of there?

EDIT: Here's an example of a custom handler that would invoke the final line:

```
  LOCATION_CHANGE: (state, action) => {

    // bootstrap
    if (_.isUndefined(state.location)) {
      state.location = action.location
    }

    state.next = {
      location: action.location,
      changed: action.changed,
    }
    state.isNavigating = true
    return state
  },
  VIEW_ROUTE_MATCH: (state, action) => {
    state.next = {
      ...state.next,
      match: action.match,
      view: action.view,
    }
    return state
  },
```

Comment: it's probably the easy solution but maybe this function can help you with deep cloning: https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep

Comment: I'm trying to migrate away from using it.

Comment: aha, it's not clear how your state looks but you can use `map` and the spread operator to copy nested arrays/objects and return a new state from the map function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you don't **need** Immer, in this instance, as you're not really making deep or complex changes, but it can still help tidy up parts. Immer's going to force three lines of code, so I stick with the spread operator if that'll keep it to one line.

```
export default (initialState, handlers = {}, promiseActionTypes = []) =>
  (state = initialState, action) => {
    let nextState = state;
    promiseActionTypes.forEach((actionType) => {
      if (action.type === `@@REMOTE/${actionType}_REQUEST`) {
        nextState = { ...nextState, isFetching: true };
      }
      if (action.type === `@@REMOTE/${actionType}_SUCCESS`) {
        nextState = produce(state, draft => {
          draft.data = _.get(action, 'data.storeData', action.data);
          draft.isFetching = false;
          draft.isInited = true;
        });
      }
      if (action.type === `@@REMOTE/${actionType}_FAILURE`) {
        nextState = { ...nextState, isFetching: false };
      }
    })

    if (handlers.hasOwnProperty(action.type)) {
      nextState = handlers[action.type](nextState, action);
    }

    return nextState
  }

const handlers = {
  LOCATION_CHANGE: (state, action) => {
    return produce(state, draft => {
      if (_.isUndefined(state.location)) {
        draft.location = action.location;
      }
      draft.next = {
        location: action.location,
        changed: action.changed,
      }
      draft.isNavigating = true
    });
  },
  VIEW_ROUTE_MATCH: (state, action) => {
    return produce(state, draft => {
      draft.match = action.match;
      draft.view = action.view;
    });
  },
}
```

Comment: Thank you-I will give this a try!

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that your original code really shouldn't have been doing a "deep clone" at all, and especially not at the top of the reducer.  That means it was doing extra work for *every* dispatched action, even if it wasn't relevant, and also likely causing the UI to re-render even if the data's values hadn't really changed.  So, as you said, a "big no-no".  Based on that, yes, I'd say Immer is useful here.

Second, you shouldn't be using `promiseActionTypes.map()` conceptually, since you're trying to do some updates instead of returning a new array.  Use `.forEach()` as the original code did.

Third, you haven't described *which* fields aren't being update properly, so it's a bit hard

Beyond that, the `draft` code looks okay.  However, the `handlers` line looks suspicious in this case.  My guess is that those additional handlers are probably doing their own immutable work, rather than attempting to "modify" the `draft` state value.  Oh, and you aren't even passing the `draft` to them anyway.  So, if you're expecting those to be generating the rest of the changes, you need to A) pass `draft` in to the handlers, and B) change them to "modify" the draft.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I think that may be the case where I have to change each individual reducer to modify the draft and not the state.

Comment: I've updated my answer with your suggestions and an example custom handler.

Comment: Any chance you can take another look Mark?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear-there isn't an issue anymore, so much as I updated my original example with more info you were missing.